# How to solve this error on sending a PUT Request from my swift app

Tags: ios, swift, rest, put

I got a url to which I have to send put request. these are headers which are being sent -, also the body looks like this - (the. second picture)

[image]

[image]

earlier I was having issues on Postman because in the cookies header, it was sending some csrftoken and now I deleted that header from my Postman put request for this URL and now it works fine, now I have to do the same thing in my Swift app - but am getting error 403, I actually hard coded the values am sending inside the body of the put request exactly as same as on postman, am only sending one header inside my put request, attaching picture below, and my URL is also the same I have printed it out as well, is this error because I have not cleared the cookies from my header field while sending a put request ?, I don't understand how to fix this please help

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[image]

here is my entire request the way am sending it -
[![enter image description here][5]][5]

[enter image description here][6]

[![enter image description here][7]][7]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .loginUser:
        return "/user/login/"
    case .getGalleryImages:
        return "/gallery/list/"
    case .getPrograms:
        return "/curriculum/academic-year"
    case .getTimeTable:
        return "/curriculum/timetable"
    case .addTimeTable(let id, _, _, _, _, _, _, _):
        return "/curriculum/timetable/\(id)/"
    }
}

var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] {
    //paginated response will include
    switch self {
    case .getPrograms(let date):
        return [
            URLQueryItem(name: "date", value: date)
        ]
    case .getTimeTable(let grade, let dayOfTheWeek):
        return [
            URLQueryItem(name: "grade", value: String(grade)),
            URLQueryItem(name: "day_of_week", value: dayOfTheWeek)
        ]
    default:
        return []
    }
    
   
}

var headers: [String : String] {
    switch self {
    case .loginUser, .addTimeTable:
        return ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
    default:
        return [:]
    }
}

var method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod {
    switch self {
    case .loginUser:
        return .post
    case .getGalleryImages, .getPrograms, .getTimeTable:
        return .get
    case .addTimeTable:
        return .put
    }
}

var url: URL? {
    var components = URLComponents(string: self.baseURLString)
    components?.path += self.path
    if !queryItems.isEmpty {
        components?.queryItems = queryItems
    }
    return components?.url
}

var request: URLRequest? {
    guard let url = self.url else { return nil }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.method = method
    request.httpBody = body
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    return request
}

var body: Data? {
    switch self {
    case .loginUser(let username, let password):
        let body: [String: String] = [
            "username": username,
            "password": password
        ]
        return try? JSONSerialization.data(
            withJSONObject: body,
            options: .fragmentsAllowed
        )
    case .addTimeTable(
        _,
        let grade,
        let subject,
        let teacher,
        let day_of_week,
        let period_number,
        let start_time,
        let end_time
    ):
        let body: [String: Any] = [
            "grade": grade,
            "subject": subject,
            "teacher": teacher,
            "day_of_week": day_of_week,
            "period_number": period_number,
            "start_time": start_time,
            "end_time": end_time
        ]
        return try? JSONSerialization.data(
            withJSONObject: body,
            options: .fragmentsAllowed
        )
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post code as text and not images

Comment: Could you share(check) your curl request from the app with the postman request? you can print the curl of your request. and also share your request code. do you use from Alamofire?

Comment: postman has 11 items in the header and in the picture you showed there is just 9 items, could you show all of them?

Comment: hi I searched this but the cURL option does not appear for my request (URLRequest type)

Comment: so the 4 hidden items are actually just the the ones I was trying to send earlier I have included a picture of them as well in the question now

Comment: A 403 error is probably because you lack authorisation to update. How are you authorising to the endpoint?

Comment: You seem to use Alamofire, Alamofire can generate a cURL code, with `cURLDescription()` to put before `.response()` and Postman can do it too. But please, make copy/paste, not only screenshot, it's harder to read, less references, etc.

Comment: hi i have removed the screenshots and added code please look into it now

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved this one - basically, i had to send the csrftoken value inside the headers as this -

```
case .addTimeTable:
        return [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Cookie": "csrftoken=\(Utils.getValue(key: Constants.CSRFTOKENVALUE))"
        ]
```